# Integrate RigidBody kinematic After Press GetAxis Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I would like to integrate the rigidbody kinematic, when I finish pressing one of the axis, because in my code after my tank moves, it keeps moving for a while as if it were a force. I tried to add it, if it stopped pressing the buttons but it didn't work.

I tried to add them in the update, or in the form of a boolean but I think I have problems to set the logic of where it should be so that it works correctly.

What I would like is for the object's kinematic to activate when the axis is released.

Thank you very much for the help

```cs
public class TankController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;              
    public float m_Speed = 12f;                
    public float m_TurnSpeed = 180f;            
    public AudioSource m_MovementAudio;         
    public float m_PitchRange = 0.2f;          
    private string m_MovementAxisName;          
    private string m_TurnAxisName;              
    private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;              
    private float m_MovementInputValue;         
    private float m_TurnInputValue;            
    private float m_OriginalPitch;             
    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // When the tank is turned on, make sure it's not kinematic.
        m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = false;

        // Also reset the input values.
        m_MovementInputValue = 0f;
        m_TurnInputValue = 0f;
    }


    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // When the tank is turned off, set it to kinematic so it stops moving.
        m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        // The axes names are based on player number.
        m_MovementAxisName = "CarroV" ;
        m_TurnAxisName = "CarroH";

        // Store the original pitch of the audio source.
       
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        // Store the value of both input axes.
        m_MovementInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_MovementAxisName);
        m_TurnInputValue = Input.GetAxis(m_TurnAxisName);
       
        EngineAudio();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Adjust the rigidbodies position and orientation in FixedUpdate.
      /*  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad8) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad4) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad6))
        {
            m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        }
        */
        Move();
        Turn();
        
    }


    private void Move()
    {
      
//m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            // Create a vector in the direction the tank is facing with a magnitude based on the input, speed and the time between frames.
            Vector3 movement = transform.forward * m_MovementInputValue * m_Speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Apply this movement to the rigidbody's position.
            m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + movement);
            
        
     
    }


    private void Turn()
    {
        
           // m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            // Determine the number of degrees to be turned based on the input, speed and time between frames.
            float turn = m_TurnInputValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Make this into a rotation in the y axis.
            Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, turn, 0f);

            // Apply this rotation to the rigidbody's rotation.
            m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rigidbody.rotation * turnRotation);
           
        
      
        /*  else
          {
              m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
          }*/
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `isKinematic`, you're telling the physics engine to not apply forces to the game object.

However, your object still has *velocity* and you need to cancel that yourself.

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad8) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad4) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad6))
{
    m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    m_Rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

**Additional consideration:**

Is there a reason you're using the physics engine? If you want it to use physics then stopping should be either using "drag" in the `RigidBody` inspector or place a force in the opposite direction:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad8) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad2) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad4) || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad6))
{
    m_Rigidbody.AddForce(-m_Rigidbody.velocity * someScalingValue); // where someScalingValue is a float you choose
}
```

If you're doing physics, you should try and keep `isKinematic` to `false`.

Alternatively *don't use the physics engine*, keep `isKinematic` set to `true` and move the transform instead.

Comment: i put the changes but it the same :/. it's looks like it rollerblading. Quiero evitar eso.

Comment: Can you add more detail to your original question - perhaps some screen shots of inspectors, your hierarchy. Or a video with it going wrong with the Physics debug section open on Rigidbody?

Comment: I think another problem is that Move() is always called. So `m_Rigidbody.MovePosition` is always called, regardless of the input.

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/i9vfyeqn This is the full code

Details : The code is used to move the tank in the environment, but when I stop pressing the movement key any of the 4. It seems that it will slide due to the impulse of the force.


What I would like is that when the movement keys stop being pressed, which are the numpad 4,8,2,6.

The car stops moving, I saw that by activating the kinematics, the car stops skidding. That's why I wanted to integrate it, but my problem is that I can't think of where in the code to put it.

Comment: In the code you've given, there's lots commented out. Please update your question with the code that you expect to work. It's not possible for me to understand what you expect from your question.